# What is wrong with my crypto price discovery bot?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, bots, algorithmic-trading

I'm following Dapp Universitie's [Create a PROFITABLE cryptocurrency trading bot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77G_-cMayRU) video.

I use git and npm install but when I run npm run start in the terminal I get the following:

> ```
> node index.js
>
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
> Require stack:
> - C:\Users\Kazuriah...index.js
> .
> .
> .
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> ```

Any ideas what went wrong? I'm sure you want to look at my code but I really didn't edit anything from the GitHub link he provides in the video other then the .env file
https://github.com/dappuniversity/price-bot

Comment: Did you install dotenv?

Comment: well I run npm install. how else would i install dotenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it looks like your `npm install` did not work as expected, and didn't install all the dependencies. I just tried cloning the repo you linked down, and was able to get all the dependencies.

The `package.json` lists `dotenv` so if it worked, it shouldn't fail.

Did you make sure to delete the `package-lock.json` file before you ran your `npm install`, because that may cause some issues if it is out of date.

Take a look at my screenshot and you can see how I went about installing it and was able to run the program, only failing because I don't have the API keys in my `.env` file.

[image: Price-bot installation Windows 10 with Cmder command prompt terminal]

Comment: Thank you this seemed to be the issue. What would you do next to solve this type error?

Comment: Well I briefly had watched that video, and I am not very into or involved in cryptocurrency. So based on what I did see, the next step would be to go to the services that are mentioned in the video (you'll have to look for yourself), sign up, and get an API key.  Copy the .env.sample file renamed as .env, and put the API key in there.